# почему при повторном вызове ConfigParser теряет комментарии?

Tags: python, парсер

Подскажите, почему при повторном вызове ConfigParser теряет комментарии?
(при первом включении добавляются комментарии, потом убираешь их из кода, и при повторном включении они пропадают, как сделать чтобы не пропадали?)

Основной код парсера:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

class MyCfg(ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, file: str='cfg.ini'):
        self.file = file
        self.optionxform = str
        return super(MyCfg, self).__init__(allow_no_value=True)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return super(MyCfg, self).__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            self.add_section(item)
            return super(MyCfg, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __setitem__(self, item, val):
        if val[0] == '#' or val[0] == ';':
            self.__getitem__(item)
            return super(MyCfg, self).set(item, val)

    def read(self):
        return super(MyCfg, self).read(self.file)

    def write(self):
        with open(self.file, 'w') as fp:
            return super(MyCfg, self).write(fp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg = MyCfg('settings.ini')
    cfg.read()
    cfg['section'] = '# Комментарий 1'
    cfg['section']['option'] = 'option_value2'
    cfg['section'] = '# Комментарий 2'
    cfg['section']['tag'] = 'tag_value'
    cfg['section'] = '# Комментарий 3'
    cfg['another_section']['test'] = 'test_value'
    cfg.write()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comment_prefixes='/'` 
использует переход на новую строку как префикс комментария,
и при чтении не удаляет комментарий как ненужный мусор.

строку:
`return super(MyCfg, self).__init__(allow_no_value=True)`

изменить на:
`return super(MyCfg, self).__init__(comment_prefixes='/', allow_no_value=True)`